# Remove correlated attributes in R

Tags: r, data-modeling, correlation

I am trying to remove the correlated attributes which are out of boundaries (-1,1). I am using the following code for the correlation:

```
cor(df[sapply(df, is.numeric)])
```

After that I get the correlation values. How can I remove the values greater than 1 and smaller -1?

Thank you

Comment: how can you get values `>1` and `< -1`  from `cor`??? please provide a piece of dataset

Comment: it is too big, it has 25 columns and 1075 row

Comment: You shouldn't have correlation values outside 1 and -1. You can replace any values outside those limits with `NA` with `ifelse(data < -1, NA, ifelse(data > 1, NA, data))`

Comment: it is works, thank you

Answer (score 0):

The cor() function in R receives a numeric vector, matrix or data frame and gives a pairwise correlation matrix of variables. Values in the correlation matrix are expected to be in the range of -1 to +1. However problems arise when we have a correlation matrix that is not positive semi definite. The most frequent cause of an invalid correlation matrix is missing values. R offers several ways of handling missing values in a correlation matrix. You can use the na.rm = TRUE option to specify all missing values should be removed (only complete rows are used).  This will always result in a valid correlation matrix.Three other options can be specified on how to handle missing observations.  The use = “all.obs” option specifies there are no missing observations and the presence of any missing values will cause an error. If use = “complete.obs” is specified case wise deletion of missing observations happens.
If use =    “pairwise.complete.obs”  is specified   only the complete pairs of observations are used. This may result in an invalid correlation matrix.